# ORACLE cursor to select a race horses position will not work

Tags: oracle, cursor

Here is the table I am trying to query from using a cursor:

```
    CREATE TABLE RaceResult 

   (RaceID NUMBER(5),
    HorseID NUMBER(5),
    JockeyID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    Position VARCHAR2 (3));
```

I have written this function to query and return all horse ID's that have come first in a race.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Horse
  (horsePOS IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  pos VARCHAR2;

  CURSOR C_Horse 
  IS
  SELECT HorseID 
  FROM RaceResult
  WHERE Position=horsePOS;

 BEGIN
 OPEN C_Horse;
 FETCH C_Horse INTO pos;-
 IF pos%notfound THEN
 pos := 9999;
 ELSE IF
 C_Horse = ('1st') THEN
 RETURN pos;

 end if;
 CLOSE C_HORSE;
 END Get_Horse;
```

It does not work, and I am beyond puzzled on what to try next.

Comment: What do you expect from `IF C_Horse = ('1st') ` ?? `C_Horse` is cursor and you can't compare it to `'1st'`

Comment: In fact there are lots of errors, End if is missing, variable declaration not proper, it seems you want horse id but returning position, note that horseid is number while pos you have taken as varchar.